# Setting the value of a Radio button on a NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a `NSButtonCell` set to style `Radio` with 1 row and 2 columns. It basically serves as a way to select from one option or the other.

How can I set the value to one or the other (but not both)?

I tried playing with:

```
[_ButtonCellSet setState:0];
```

But that's not the solution.

This is done on XCode 4.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this is to put the radio buttons in an `NSMatrix` and use `selectCellAtRow:column:` to change the selection. This code will toggle the selection back and forth between two radio buttons in a 1x2 matrix:

```
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    cursel = 1 - cursel;
    [radioGroup selectCellAtRow:0 column:cursel];
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this. What's cursel, an integer?